# How to solve "IServiceProvider" is ambiguous when using "wininet" and "windows.h"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to check if the internet connection exists or not by using the `InternetCheckConnection` function of `wininet`.

Here's my **CheckerClass:** which handles the process of checking.

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"wininet.lib")
#include <String>

public ref class CheckerClass
{
public:
    static std::string hasInternet() {
        bool bConnect = InternetCheckConnection(L"https://www.google.com", FLAG_ICC_FORCE_CONNECTION, 0);
        if (bConnect){
            return "Has Internet!";
        }else{
            return "No Internet!";
        }
    }
};
```

But I'm getting the following error and I can't solve it.

```
Error (active)  E1986   an ordinary pointer to a C++/CLI ref class or interface class is not allowed
Error (active)  E0266   "IServiceProvider" is ambiguous
Error   C3699   '*': cannot use this indirection on type 'IServiceProvider'
```

After searching, I found this can because of using `using namespace System`, but I don't have that in the above class.

However, I have the following from **Main** class where I'm using the above class.

```
#pragma once
#include<string>
#include "CheckerClass.h"
namespace CppCLRWinformsProjekt {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    using std::string;

    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:

        CheckerClass checkerClass;
        
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string result = checkerClass.hasInternet();
            this->label_output->Text = gcnew System::String(result.c_str());
        }

    .....
```

Can anybody explain what's going on and how can I solve the above issue?

Comment: These are .h files, you haven't yet found the .cpp file that #includes them.  And contains using namespace System, thus screwing up the Windows.h declarations.  One obvious bug you *should* get a diagnostic about is the checkerClass variable, must be declared as CheckerClass^.

Comment: @HansPassant - I have issues with the class I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of `CheckerClass` do you have? Classes are normally split up into two files. Which mean you should have `CheckerClass.h` and `CheckerClass.cpp`. Where is that code above from those two files?

In any case, here's example of a working class base on your code.

In your `CheckerClass.h` file, you should have;

```
#include <string>
#ifndef CHECKER_CLASS_H
#define CHECKER_CLASS_H
using std::string;
class CheckerClass {

private:
    //declare private variables here, if you need one.
public:

    CheckerClass(); 
    
    string hasInternet(); //The function
};
#endif
```

Then the implementation of the class goes into the `CheckerClass.cpp` file;

```
#include "CheckerClass.h"
#include "string"
#include "windows.h"
#include "wininet.h"
#pragma comment(lib,"wininet.lib")

CheckerClass::CheckerClass() {
    //initialize variable here if needed.
}

std::string CheckerClass::hasInternet() {
    bool bConnect = InternetCheckConnection(L"https://www.google.com", FLAG_ICC_FORCE_CONNECTION, 0);
    if (bConnect) {
        return "has Internet";
    }
    else {
        return "no internet";
    }
}
```

Then you can now get the result with your code;

```
string result = checkerClass.hasInternet();
this->label_output->Text = gcnew System::String(result.c_str());
```

This will avoid the conflicts and the error your having with.

Comment: So basically, the conflicts happened because I did not initialize my class properly. I got a little confused with `h` file and `cpp` file. I thought the concept of making class on C++ and Java are just the same. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is because `using namespace System;` conflicts with the name in `Windows.h`,

`Windows.h` introduced `servprov.h` indirect. And `servprov.h` has this definition: `typedef interface IServiceProvider IServiceProvider;`
Among them, `IServiceProvider` conflicts with `IServiceProvider` in the System namespace, causing uncertainty.

The solution is to use the fully qualified name instead of the System namespace, such as `System::IServiceProvider`.

Comment: Can you tell me more about it? Where should I do that? Because I tried removing the namespace related to `System` from the main class and still getting the same issue. I tried using `System::IServiceProvider` on `CheckerClass` and still getting the same issue.

Comment: You could try to comment out all `using namespace System;` When using `IServiceProvider`, use `System::IServiceProvider` instead. There is another possibility. Look thourgh your included files whether there are two namespace settings enabled in a subfile. For example, `using namespace System;` `using namespace System::IO;` Conflict was coused by duplicate settings in one of the included files.

Comment: So basically, the conflicts happened because I did not initialize my class properly. I got a little confused with `h` file and `cpp` file. I thought the concept of making class on C++ and Java are just the same. Thank you!